# Memory leak when creating pixel buffer of image

Tags: ios, swift, core-video

I am trying to create a video with an input of images using AVAssetWriterInput for which I need to create a pixel buffer of my images.

For that I call the function below which works, but after creating a few videos the app receives a memory warning and crashes. I have debugged it using Instruments and it appears I have a memory leak [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkwqF.png).

I have tried to put the variables pixelBufferPointer and pxData as class variables and destroy/dealloc once the video is created but that didn't appear to make any difference. Is there something that I should be doing to release this memory?

```
func createPixelBufferFromCGImage(image: CGImageRef) -> CVPixelBufferRef {
    let options = [
        "kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey": true,
        "kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey": true
    ]

    var videoWidth = 496
    var videoHeight = 668

    let frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(videoWidth), CGFloat(videoHeight))

    var pixelBufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>?>.alloc(1)

    var status:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        Int(frameSize.width),
        Int(frameSize.height),
        OSType(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
        options,
        pixelBufferPointer
    )

    var lockStatus:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue(), 0)

    var pxData:UnsafeMutablePointer<(Void)> = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue())

    let bitmapinfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipFirst.rawValue)
    let rgbColorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var context:CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        pxData,
        Int(frameSize.width),
        Int(frameSize.height),
        8,
        //4 * CGImageGetWidth(image),
        4 * Int(frameSize.width),
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapinfo
    )

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image)

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer.memory?.takeUnretainedValue(), 0)

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return pixelBufferPointer.memory!.takeUnretainedValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>` is leaking.

I would prefer Russell Austin's answer, but I couldn't figure out how to pass the `pixelBufferPointer` to `CVPixelBufferCreate` without syntax error (swift noob). Failing that, changing the line

```
return pixelBufferPointer.memory!.takeUnretainedValue()
```

to

```
return pixelBufferPointer.memory!.takeRetainedValue()
```

fixes the leak

Comment: Which issue @RB1509?

Comment: thanks for your reply :) i have an issue regarding record a view and i am not able to ask question so can you please help me to short out it?

Comment: var buffer:CVPixelBuffer?
                    autoreleasepool {
                        buffer = self.pixelBufferFromImage(image: image)
                    }
                    if buffer != nil {
                        let result = self.adapter.append(buffer!, withPresentationTime: present)
                        if !result {
                            print(self.writer.error)
                        }
                        
                        buffer = nil
                    }

Comment: that is my code i can't able to provide full code but i debug as well and this code take memory upto 1.34 Gb on my device while recording view, it occurs crash. one more thing that code is in writeVideoFromImageFrames which will use to convert video from images.

Comment: You need to show some more code, especially `pixelBufferFromImage` - why can't you ask a question?

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: it shows me like this whenever i try to ask question.

Comment: wait i will share you link where you can see my code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10of8wqXaw2_XVZctpshVNly7Z156ikMT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please check it.

Comment: there i make 2 function for cvpixelbuffer. one of them i used in my code but that crash on memory leaks.

Comment: you need to ask a new question with the above code. fwiw it looks like `frameBuffer` is never drained

Comment: frameBuffer is never drained. Means ??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Memory leak on CIContext createCGImage at iOS 9?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/50981#50981)

I'm having a similar issue, the leak is due to the following code

```
CGImageRef processedCGImage = [_context createCGImage:ciImage
                                                             fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
```

Here for more contextual info: [Memory Leak in CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685756/memory-leak-in-cmsamplebuffergetimagebuffer)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am not sure if it is the same bug because I am running this code on iOS 8.3 and I am also not using createCGImage

Comment: that is right, but I have some suspects, infact those primitives CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress, CGBitmapContextCreate, CGContextDrawImage are the same used when dealing with a createCGImage using a CIContext. I'm sure they are related.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the UnsafeMutablePointer types. You were probably trying to convert from some Objective-C example. I was doing the same thing but eventually found how to do it without. Try

```
var pixelBufferPointer: CVPixelBuffer?
...
var status:CVReturn = CVPixelBufferCreate(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    Int(frameSize.width),
    Int(frameSize.height),
    OSType(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
    options,
    &pixelBufferPointer
)
```

and

```
var pxData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBufferPointer)
```

Then you don't have to do the takeUnRetainedValue, etc.

You might also try using AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor and a pixel buffer pool. That is supposed to be more efficient. [See this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28968322/how-would-i-put-together-a-video-using-the-avassetwriter-in-swift/32785160#32785160)

Comment: i already set that code but it seems memory leak from buffer while frames in loop.

Answer (score 0):

When using `CVPixelBufferCreate` the `UnsafeMutablePointer` has to be **destroyed** after retrieving the `memory` of it.

When I create a `CVPixelBuffer`, I do it like this:

```
func allocPixelBuffer() -> CVPixelBuffer {
    let pixelBufferAttributes : CFDictionary = [...]
    let pixelBufferOut = UnsafeMutablePointer<CVPixelBuffer?>.alloc(1)
    _ = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 
                            Int(Width), 
                            Int(Height), 
                            OSType(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
                            pixelBufferAttributes, 
                            pixelBufferOut)

    let pixelBuffer = pixelBufferOut.memory!
    pixelBufferOut.destroy()
    return pixelBuffer
}
```